# how i can fetch selected item through session?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying you display selected product on page from another page through session but session fetch all products.

But if i use query string it `enter code here` only fetch one product which selected.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please put code in question not in image.

Comment: You can set product id in session from the other page and use session here to fetch that product id, but for such task querystring should be used instead of session. As session will get overriden if you click on another product.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
              //  string[] input =Session["data"].ToString().Split('\'');
         string[] input=Session["data"].ToString().Split('\'');
               
             //  string[] input = HttpContext.Current.Session["data"].ToString().Split('\'');
             //  string[] input = Request.QueryString["product_detail"].Split('\'');
                string Params = input[1]; //Substring(, input.Length - 2);

Comment: Dinesh Prajapati, The main issue when I used query string is about length

Comment: @ImranAli Code should be in question not in comments.

Comment: @Leopard i want to know that in query string if I write Request.QueryString["product_detail"], it select just one item or we can say just a product. So which attribute of session i should use to replace QueryString

Comment: You will not directly get the value in session, if you have not set it. You need to set the value in session in order to be able to use it. Search for the code which sets product_detail in querystring. Search "product_detail" you will be able to find it, it would have been appended in URL.

Comment: product_detail is current class where item will display